# Angular 5 Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular

I have a list group which gets data from a rest service using HttpClient Post method.

I get "Cannot find a differ supporting object error" intermittently. But when I refresh the browser the data is displayed and if I try to switch between compoenents, I can still see the data. But after 10 mins or so if I click try to access any component on the page, I get above error.

Below is my code. Can you help me identifying what I am doing wrong?

**component.html**

```
<div class="list-group">
        <a
          routerLinkActive="active"
          routerLink="/home/switchroles/{{ account.acc_name }}"
          class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pl-1 pr-1 pt-1 pb-0 rounded-0"
          *ngFor="let account of allAccounts">{{ account.acc_dname }}
          <!--<span class="badge badge-pill badge-dark float-right">{{ account.Roles.length }}</span>-->
        </a>
      </div>
```

**component.ts**

```
export class SwitchRolesComponent implements OnInit {
  allAccounts: Account[] = [];
  accountsCount: number;
  loading: boolean;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private dataservice: DataService) {
    this.loading = true;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataservice.getAllAccounts().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.allAccounts = res;
        this.accountsCount = res.length;
        this.loading = false;
      },
      err => {
        console.log('Error Occoured');
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**getAllAccounts function from a dataservice**

```
getAllAccounts(): Observable<Account[]> {
    return this.http.post<Account[]>('https://rest-url/Prod/getdata', {
      'operation': 'SelectFromMySQLDB',
      'data': {
        'query': 'select query here'
      }
    });
  }
```

**Account Class**

```
export class Account {
  constructor(
    public acc_name: string,
    public acc_dname: string,
    public acc_number: string,
    public acc_roles: string,
    public acc_desc: string,
  ) {}
}
```

**Edit: Pring {{ allAccounts | json }}**

```
[
    {
        "idawsaccounts": 11,
        "acc_name": "test1",
        "acc_dname": "Test1",
        "acc_number": "123456789",
        "acc_roles": "Test roles",
        "acc_desc": "Test Desc"
    },
    {
        "idawsaccounts": 12,
        "acc_name": "test2",
        "acc_dname": "Test2",
        "acc_number": "123456789",
        "acc_roles": "Test roles",
        "acc_desc": "Test Desc"
    },
    {
        "idawsaccounts": 13,
        "acc_name": "test3",
        "acc_dname": "Test3",
        "acc_number": "123456789",
        "acc_roles": "Test roles",
        "acc_desc": "Test Desc"
    }
]
```

Comment: I think that the object you received in your response isn't an array.

Comment: I am receiving an array of Objects of type Account defined in my account class.

Comment: Try to print only `allAccounts` in template with json pipe. Ex: {{allAccounts | json}} and see what happens. Remove all the template. Just print `allAccounts`

Comment: ngFor only supports Iterates such as Array, so you cannot use it for Object

Comment: If it were an array, you wouldn't get this error message

Comment: Then you definitely iterating an object or something else but not array

Comment: It's look like you change "allAccounts" in somewhere

Comment: @AshrafulIslam Edited my question with output of {{ allAccounts | json }}. I also tried declaring allAccounts as any[] but the result is same. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If I am not iterating an array how can I see the data first time when I load the page? It is happening intermittently. It again works when I refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit - Solved**

The issue is not with the Java Script code and you guys were right, I am not iterating an array when error occured.

The issue is with the backend rest service. If the backend function is successful it returns an array of objects. But for some reason if it fails it returns a JSON object and that is when I get this error which is genuine.

Now I need to fix my backend service to callback an array even when it fails or check for the return value in my Angular code and iterate only if it is an array. If it is a JSON object I need to display an error message.

Thanks a lot for your inputs.

Comment: I was expecting this from the very beginning but you always insist that you were iterating an array. ok best of luck

Answer (score 0):

look you can't say if you declare that property as array then the service will return data as array. When setting value in property from the service console.log there to know what is the current type of your data. It will make a sense